# Can I add conditions in app.config file?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, configuration-files

Is it possible to add conditions in app.config file?

I do below in the C# code and I want to do something similar in my `app.config` file too.

```
#if (Debug)
.......
#else
.....
#endif
```

Answer (score 11):

You can try some type of `app.config` transforms like this: http://fknut.blogspot.com/2009/11/appconfig-transformation-with-new.html.

Or have multiple `app.config` files like `app.config.debug` and `app.config.release`, and use the appropriate one in your build.

Answer (score 4):

That is not possible, although in Visual Studio 2010 there is a feature that lets you apply [configuration-dependent transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) to the Web.config file, but only when publishing using msdeploy.

There is no such transformation for executable applications. You might want to look into using a post-build action to copy a release or debug config file.

Comment: For executable application the same can now be achived with https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this programatically, by putting the relevant sections in two different config files, then at app-start time, load the appropriate config file. The majority of your config would be in the main app.config, and there would be a second config file for the rest.

I don't have the syntax offhand, but it's basically the same idea as having a user.config with user-specific configurations.